# When reload a page, it jumps to the top, using turbolinks and overflow hidden on html and body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overflow, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I have a project on `Rails 5.1.4`. As it is said in the title of this question, reloading a page causes it to jump to the top of it. But I want the page to stay in the same position that was before reloading. In my `css` I have these styles:

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If I comment them, the behaviour of `turbolinks` is exact as I need. Is there any way to leave these styles and force `turbolinks` after page reload stay in the same position? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Are you using javascript along with css? Turbolinks usually affects how .js is loaded.

Comment: Sure, I use js. And all my js is loading like: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){...});`. But, `turbolinks` begin to work when I comment or remove the styles above.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "reloading"? Is it when you perform a full page refresh? or is it when you revisit a page by clicking a link? Are you able to link to a demonstration of the issue?

Comment: Exactly! After a page refresh jumps to the top. The behaviour is similar here: https://www.vojoodmedia.com/

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, the way Turbolinks works affect how .js files are loaded by the browser.

That is because all js/css/html files are loaded for a new page, but because Turbolinks caches all those files, .js files are not processor again when reloaded the page. Therefore, you may have a .js file (maybe a plugin) that affects the .css in your page.

One way to solve this problem is to render the element affected by .js always when the page is loaded. You can do that through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this is an issue with Turbolinks, but rather with how browsers behave by default. Browsers store the scroll position of the *document* before navigating away so that it can be reinstated when reloaded or when navigating back. (Turbolinks replicates this behaviour.)

By applying `overflow: hidden;` to the `html` element, the document element cannot be scrolled and therefore the scroll position will always be 0. With that CSS, it is the `body` element that is actually being scrolled rather than the document.

To demonstrate this, here is a non-turbolinks page with that CSS: http://output.jsbin.com/mikopor Notice that if you scroll down and refresh, the page will return to the top.

If possible, I'd recommend removing `html { overflow: hidden; }`.

Hope that helps